# Git log within specific files change

Tags: git, version-control, git-log

I was wondering if there is a way to find the git log with AND, OR etc operations on files params. For example, I see,

```
git log file1 file2
```

provides me the logs where any of the content of those file1, file2 has been changed. But my intention is to find logs where both files have been changed. So, logically i want something like,

```
git log (file1 & file2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use git log to archive it:

**OR** operation: `git log file1 file2`

**AND** opteration: `git log file1 | git log file2`